# jasper report display static text below dynamic content table

Tags: jasper-reports

[image: design text under table]

[image: preview]

I would like to display some static text under the table. The table content is generated dynamically from JSON data. But in the preview, the static text displays in the table.
How to solve this problem by adding some options to the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.  I have moved the static text to a new detail band. Next time when we create a dynamic data table, we'd better put it and other content to separate detail bands. Then the detail band could stretch automatically.